# servervalidate function of my custom validator doesn't fire .net

Tags: asp.net, validation

In Page.Load I add dynamically a label,my textbox which should be valdiated and the customvalidator

```
Label myLabel3 = new Label();
                    myLabel3.ID = "lblEGN" + i.ToString();
                    myLabel3.Text = "EГН";
                    TextBox myTextBox3 = new TextBox();
                    myTextBox3.ID = "txtEGN" + i.ToString();
                    pnlPersonalCard.Controls.Add(myLabel3);
                    pnlPersonalCard.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                    CustomValidator cvEGN = new CustomValidator();
                    cvEGN.ID = "cvtxtEGN" + i.ToString();
                    cvEGN.ControlToValidate = "txtEGN" + i.ToString();
                   // cvEGN.ClientValidationFunction = "checkEgn";
                    cvEGN.ServerValidate += serverCheckEgn;
                    cvEGN.ErrorMessage = "Невалидно егн";
                    pnlPersonalCard.Controls.Add(cvEGN);


                    pnlPersonalCard.Controls.Add(myTextBox3);
                    pnlPersonalCard.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
```

of course i provide the custom validate function whichshould be executed

```
protected void  serverCheckEgn(object sender,  ServerValidateEventArgs args) {
            string egn = args.Value;

            if (egn.Length != 10)
                args.IsValid = false;

            int year = Int32.Parse(egn.Substring(0, 2));
            int month = Int32.Parse(egn.Substring(2, 4));
            int day = Int32.Parse(egn.Substring(4, 6));

            if (month >= 40) {
                year += 2000;
                month -= 40;
            } else if (month >= 20) {
                year += 1800;
                month -= 20;
            } else {
                year += 1900;
            }


            string date = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;

            if (!CheckDate(date))
                args.IsValid=false;

            int checkSum = 0;
            int[] weights = new int[9] {2,4,8,5,10,9,7,3,6};

            for (var ii = 0; ii < weights.Length; ++ii) {
                checkSum += weights[ii] * Int32.Parse(egn.Substring(ii,1));
            }

            checkSum %= 11;
            checkSum %= 10;

            if (checkSum != Int32.Parse(egn.Substring(9,1)))
                args.IsValid=false;

            args.IsValid = true;
        }
```

But when i press my button all the other validitators (I got two other requiredfield valdiators and two other regularexpressionvalidator ) are working only this custom validator doesn't it seems that the function which I provide doesn't execute!

Comment: can you say example of input date

Comment: example - 555; the field is very important and the data should be really exact - it's the most important personal number in bulgaria for each person

Comment: When are the controls dynamically added to your page ? Dynamically added controls won't trigger their events if they are not added on Init of the page.

Comment: how to obtain Substring(4, 6) of '555'

Comment: Yes Samiey - I wrote that I found out my mistake. Just look. Now I got another problem

Comment: if you find out solution, edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

during insert record to database check the IsValid:

```
if (page.IsValid) 
{
    //insert record
}
else
{
    Response.Write("Input string is incorrect!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the content of the textbox empty when you're trying to validate? To validate when empty you need to set `ValidateEmptyText` property is set to `true`

Comment: No! The content of the textbox is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Guys you can't believe what caused the problem 
when I write in the textbox - 5555

and and when the program reach this line

```
 int day = Int32.Parse(egn.Substring(4, 6));
```

I ofcourse get the exception that the character I want to substract is  outside the range of my string.

And the problem is another. Even  in my button_click function I got this line

```
if (page.IsValid)
```

to check if everything is OK before inserting in the database; I don't know why but the record is inserted in the database event though args.IsValid=false